# Joining 2 columns where 1 column has unique records and the other has duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have 2 column Risk_Geo_ID in one table which has duplicates and Geography_Identifier in other table which has unique records. Doing an inner join is giving me duplicate records and cannot process this query in cube as Geography_Identifier is a PK and its unique. Need a query to get unique records. 
Here is the Code:

```
SELECT     
s.Geography_Identifier     
,s.State_Code    
,s.State_Name     
,s.County_Name    
,s.City_Name    
,s.ZIP_Code     
,a.Risk_ID      
,a.Risk_Address     
,a.Latitude    
,a.Longitude     
,a.Distance_to_Coast    
,a.Insurance_Score    
FROM [Policy].[Dim_Risk] AS a    
INNER JOIN [Policy].[Fact_Monthly_Policy_Snap] AS b    
ON b.Risk_ID = a.Risk_ID    
AND b.Insurance_score = a.Insurance_Score    
INNER JOIN [Common].[Dim_Geography] AS s    
ON b.Risk_Geo_ID =  s.Geography_Identifier
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `CROSS APPLY` with `TOP 1` if you want to get just one row with such `ID`:

```
SELECT     
 q.Geography_Identifier     
,s.State_Code    
,s.State_Name     
,s.County_Name    
,s.City_Name    
,s.ZIP_Code     
,a.Risk_ID      
,a.Risk_Address     
,a.Latitude    
,a.Longitude     
,a.Distance_to_Coast    
,a.Insurance_Score    
FROM [Policy].[Dim_Risk] AS a    
INNER JOIN [Policy].[Fact_Monthly_Policy_Snap] AS b    
ON b.Risk_ID = a.Risk_ID    
AND b.Insurance_score = a.Insurance_Score  
CROSS APPLY
( 
   SELECT 
   TOP 1
   *
   FROM [Common].[Dim_Geography] AS s    
   WHERE s.Geography_Identifier = b.Risk_Geo_ID
)q
```

Comment: Is that DISTINCT of Unique column Geography_Identifier or DISTINCT of Duplicate column Risk_Geo_ID?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT works on the whole selected rows - all columns!

Comment: @Sam show, please, your sample data and desired output.

Comment: @SathiyaKumar `DISTINCT` is applied to the whole set, so I decided to use `cross apply`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the distinct

```
SELECT     
distinct s.Geography_Identifier     
,s.State_Code    
,s.State_Name     
,s.County_Name    
,s.City_Name    
,s.ZIP_Code     
,a.Risk_ID      
,a.Risk_Address     
,a.Latitude    
,a.Longitude     
,a.Distance_to_Coast    
,a.Insurance_Score    
FROM [Policy].[Dim_Risk] AS a    
INNER JOIN [Policy].[Fact_Monthly_Policy_Snap] AS b    
ON b.Risk_ID = a.Risk_ID    
AND b.Insurance_score = a.Insurance_Score    
INNER JOIN [Common].[Dim_Geography] AS s    
ON b.Risk_Geo_ID =  s.Geography_Identifier
```